# jquery color changer save

Tags: jquery, save

I've made a color changer in jQuery which basically just changes the colors of h1, h2, a, navbar etc. - now I just need to work out a way to make these colors save, the best way would be if they completely saves so when people visits again, the color is still changed, otherwise I could also be satisfied with the color just saving on page changes etc. How can I achieve this? My coding might not be the best since I'm still a newbie, but it works. Here it is:

http://pastie.org/private/agmkir1lsrf0qe0hlvzg

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for it to save on the user's computer, you'll want to look at [HTML5 storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or store it in a cookie (easy done with libraries like [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)). Each method of storage has it's own benefits/disadvantages so you'll want to make sure what you choose is adequate.

If it needs stored on a server, that's a significantly bigger challenge depending on what the existing setup is. I'd look into just saving it via an Ajax call in that case.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your fast response, but I am still wondering how I'm able to save the user's choice of color through one of those methods. It works this way; The user clicks one of 4 boxes to choose the color they want, jQuery will then change the color of the h1, h2, navbar etc. but I need the choice to be stored, how do I actually "log" the box they click and make it save locally on their PC or browser?